# Yandex MapKit. Kotlin. Mark is not displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, yandex-maps

I use Yandex MapKit in my app. My mapView is on a fragment. It works well. Zoom also works.
But a mark which I added with addPlacemark() is not displayed. I cannot resolve this issue.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        checkPermission()
        fusedClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())

        fusedClient.getCurrentLocation(
            Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
            object : CancellationToken() {
                override fun onCanceledRequested(p0: OnTokenCanceledListener) =
                    CancellationTokenSource().token

                override fun isCancellationRequested() = false
            }).addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                currentLatitude = location.latitude
                currentLongitude = location.longitude
                binding.mapview.mapWindow.map.move(
                    CameraPosition(
                        Point(currentLatitude, currentLongitude),
                        /* zoom = */ 16.0f,
                        /* azimuth = */ 0f,
                        /* tilt = */ 0f
                    )
                )
                val imageProvider = ImageProvider.fromResource(requireContext(), ic_action_name)
                val placemark = binding.mapview.mapWindow.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark()
                placemark.geometry = Point(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)
                placemark.setIcon(imageProvider)
                placemark.setText("Обязательно к посещению!")

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "NO COORDINATES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        return view
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problen is svg-image. Yandex MapKit does not work with this format I changed it on png.  Now placemark works.